# My Java project doesn't print out anything

Tags: java

Here is my code:

```
public class Code {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       reverse(-123);

    }

    public static int reverse(int x) {

        String str = Integer.toString(x);
        char c[] = new char[str.length()];
        for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
            c[i] = str.charAt(str.length() - 1 - i);

        }
        if (c[str.length()-1] == '-') {
            for (int i=c.length-2; i >=0; i--) {
                c[i+1] = c[i];
            }
            c[0] = '-';
        }
        String n = new String(c);
        int re = Integer.parseInt(n);
        return re;

    }
}
```

I'm doing a Java exercise which is to change the order of an Integer to reverse with the '-' in it, but when I run the program, it doesn't print out anything, please help me solve this!!

Comment: There are no print statements in your code.

Comment: Do this `System.out.println(reverse(-123));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
       System.out.println(reverse(-123));
    }
```

should work now, you missed print statement.

Comment: oh my god, I'm so silly, thanks for your relying btw

Comment: @NamTrường oh it's okay, sometimes we miss. Please Accept answer if resolved :)

Comment: Just curious, why you changed your mind to mark the answer unaccepted?

Comment: Oh sorry, I thought i could mark more than 1 correct answer, let me mark it again, you are the first person answering anyway

Comment: oh I see,  you can always click up arrow to vote up if you like any answers @NamTrường

Answer (score 0):

Just add System.out.println where you called the function reverse

public class Code {

```
/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
   System.out.println(reverse(-123));

}

public static int reverse(int x) {

    String str = Integer.toString(x);
    char c[] = new char[str.length()];
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
        c[i] = str.charAt(str.length() - 1 - i);

    }
    if (c[str.length()-1] == '-') {
        for (int i=c.length-2; i >=0; i--) {
            c[i+1] = c[i];
        }
        c[0] = '-';
    }
    String n = new String(c);
    int re = Integer.parseInt(n);
    return re;

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

To print we need to add a print statement i.e,
`System.out.println(reverse(-123));`